# How to return selected values from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a question on how to get the values back to PHP code when I select few values from dropdown as shown in below picture.

[image]

The code for table display and supporting html is written in a **abc.php** file.
Now when i select few values from dropdown I want to display the data of remaining columns for the values selected.

The code used for dropdown is

```
<dl class="dropdown"> 
    <dt>
        <a href="#" class="<?php echo str_replace(" ","",str_replace("`","",$cols_array[$i]))."_jq" ; ?>">
            <span class="hida">Select</span>    
            <p class="multiSel"></p>  
        </a><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <div class="mutliSelect">
            <ul style="width: 150px;" class="<?php echo str_replace(" ","",str_replace("`","",$cols_array[$i]))."_ul" ; ?>" id="ulist1">
                <?php for($t=0;$t<$total_values;$t++){ ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" name ="<?php str_replace(" ","",str_replace("`","",$cols_array[$i]))."_name[]" ?>" value="<?php echo $col_values[$t] ?>"><?php echo $col_values[$t] ?>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

I want to get the selected values to the same **abc.php** file and display data for those values on the same page again.

Please guide me on this.
Please show me a code if you are using autopostback or jquery or sending variable from jquery/javascript to php file.

Comment: This is too broad, you're asking for us to provide you with a solution. That's not really what we do here. Come up with a solution and if it doesn't work, let us and know we can help you out. I'd look at jQuery and jQuery UI for a solution to this problem.

Comment: function get-values()()
    {
        var option_value = document.getElementById("ulist1").value;
        var dataString = 'value=' + option_value;

    // AJAX code to submit form.    
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "selectedfields.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        document.getElementById("retvals").innerHTML=html;
    }
    });
    return false;
    }        this is my ajax code